# Forms in jsp, what to use instead of hidden field

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, servlets

I'm very new to jsp and is unfortunately working with Websphere 5. I'm now trying to make a simple web page that can show information from the enterprise beans and got instructed to send information from the jsp-page to the servlet via a hidden field in the form. This seems like a sort of out dated way to do things. Are there better ways?

As I said, I'm new to the jsp-part, but do know Java and html, but no JavaScript.

Grateful for help!

Comment: Why do you think it's outdated? i find it the best way to send form data to the page which is nessesary for some operations and does not need to be displayed.

Comment: I do not think **form fields** are outdated. Form fields are useful to send data from one page to another page. [check this][1] [1]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Hidden_form_fields

Comment: Hi! As I said, I'm new to this and to me it seemed like a kind of ugly way to do it. But maybe I'm wrong. I was looking for a discussion on what solutions are available, but thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so you want

- store some data used by jsp and servlet
- want it to be hidden to user
- No html hidden form element.
- No javascript

how about maintain the data in session object?

Comment: I was thinking about that and will give it a try!